# UWP full-screen mode: how NOT to show taskbar/blue rectangle on mouse move

Tags: uwp

I have UWP running in full-screen mode. When I move the mouse to the bottom of the screen I can see the taskbar (`FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Standard`) or blue rectangle(`FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal`). I.e.
[image]
[image]

Is there any way NOT to show a taskbar/blue rectangle at all?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is unfortunately not possible. The reason for this is to make sure the user is always able to exit from the application/multitask normally.

The only workaround would probably be the [kiosk mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/partnerapps/create-a-kiosk-app-for-assigned-access), but this is for not for general use.